# How to make custom firebase events in Unity android project?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

Firebase provides some default events like level_up.
Here is how you can call this event in code:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventLevelUp, new Parameter(FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterLevel, levelNumber));
```

I`ve tried making my own events like this (the way firebase quickstart project does it):

```
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("Player pressed the button", "Button name", someIntvalue));
```

Basically sending parameters as strings.

I`ve also tried writing this function like that:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("Player pressed the button", new Parameter("Button name", someIntValue));
```

None of these two variants get registered in debug view of firebase analytics, but the default events do.

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some of the code prior to setting up your event? As well as your authentication code?

Comment: Here is the whole script: https://pastebin.com/vcnN75cx it contains some code from the firebase example unity project (i`m not sure what it is supposed to do), some default events and one of my own event (I commented it as //MY OWN EVENT). I call this static functions from other scripts when a certain event happens.

Comment: And all other events are working, just not your own FrostCharges event?

Comment: Are you looking at the parameter reporting tab in Firebase? That's where custom parameters will appear.

Comment: Yes, all other events are working, in parameter reporting tab (which is in events tab) I only have "earn_virtual_currency" event. Maybe i`m looking in the wrong place? Here is the screenshot from events panel: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1i5wpt1n83lwr6/noname.png?dl=0

Comment: And this is the screenshot from reporting tab: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uaa5wh4nu41tqe/noname2.png?dl=0

Answer (score 6):

You should replace the spaces in the event names with underscores. I believe that you're not following the rules for event names:

> Event names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an alphabetic character. The "firebase_", "google_", and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not be used.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/group/event-names

Comment: Thank you, I`ve missed that. I`ll try that tomorrow and tell if it fixes the problem.

Comment: No problem! It took me a little searching to find that quote myself, and I sort of knew what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, replacing spaces with "_" solved the problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
 FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("get_gems_click : ", "get_gems_click", 1);
```